# Efficient way to map matrix int values to str with numpy

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I am calculating similarity between embedding  vectors
My matrix shape is (16480,300) --> vecs

```
vecs[0]
array([ 0.10071956,  3.8815327 ,  0.12835003, -0.31677222,  0.70524615,
        0.65897983, -0.7154368 ,  4.49739   ,  0.77070695, -2.3327951 ,
       -3.7463412 ,  0.8334273 ,  2.2104564 , -2.0296195 ,  0.6603169 ,
       -3.0648541 , -1.9763994 ,  3.8416848 , -0.22661261,  0.4862857 ,....]
```

I am using hnswlib for approximate calculation of similarity
the output calculations of n=10 is matrix with shape of (16480,10) --> labels
each row of the labels matrix is the most similar vectors from the vecs matrix
each column represent the index of vector in the vecs matrix

```
labels[0]
array([ 7791,  1593,  3561,  2280,  2920,  3588, 13151,  5673,  7562,
        4148], dtype=uint64
```

i have a df for storing the 'str' value corresponding to the vectors matrix 
df['ind']

```
0        1.1000659
1         1.100087
2        1.1001568
3        1.1008761
4        1.1018004

16476     1.992905
16477     1.993998
16478     1.995835
16479      1.99836
16480     1.999198
Name: ind, Length: 16481, dtype: object
```

My goal is to map the labels matrix to json of 'str' in purpose to write in to mongoDB as:

```
{'1.1000659 ' : [{'1.00xxx','1.0xxx'...n10}]
 '1.xx': ....n10}
```

Now the matrices is small and will scale to 500k so the indexing will take longer

for getting the string value for the index i am running this code:

```
{df.iloc[i]['ind']:df.iloc[labels[i]]['ind'] for i in range(labels.shape[0])}
```

run time ~ 12 for 16,400 rows
There is another approach for mapping "vectorize"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use indexing `df.ind` with `labels` once added a dimension with `None`. Not sure of your exact expected output, but something like:

```
#dummy input
np.random.seed(16)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ind': ['1.001', '1.002', '1.003', '1.004', '1.005', 
                           '1.006', '1.007', '1.008', '1.009', '1.010']})
labels = np.random.randint(0,9, size=(10, 4))

# see what does the indexing
print (df.ind[:,None][labels].reshape(labels.shape).tolist())
[['1.006' '1.002' '1.005' '1.005']
 ['1.001' '1.001' '1.009' '1.003']
 ['1.005' '1.001' '1.002' '1.003']
 ['1.005' '1.001' '1.006' '1.003']
 ['1.004' '1.009' '1.003' '1.006']
 ['1.005' '1.002' '1.009' '1.005']
 ['1.006' '1.007' '1.008' '1.006']
 ['1.009' '1.001' '1.007' '1.009']
 ['1.006' '1.003' '1.005' '1.003']
 ['1.002' '1.009' '1.008' '1.002']]

# create the result you want
d = {ind: val for ind, val in zip(df.ind, df.ind[:,None][labels].reshape(labels.shape).tolist())}
print (d)
{'1.001': ['1.006', '1.002', '1.005', '1.005'],
 '1.002': ['1.001', '1.001', '1.009', '1.003'],
 '1.003': ['1.005', '1.001', '1.002', '1.003'],
 '1.004': ['1.005', '1.001', '1.006', '1.003'],
 '1.005': ['1.004', '1.009', '1.003', '1.006'],
 '1.006': ['1.005', '1.002', '1.009', '1.005'],
 '1.007': ['1.006', '1.007', '1.008', '1.006'],
 '1.008': ['1.009', '1.001', '1.007', '1.009'],
 '1.009': ['1.006', '1.003', '1.005', '1.003'],
 '1.010': ['1.002', '1.009', '1.008', '1.002']}
```

Comment: 800~ time faster :)